# Broken System after upgrade Fedora 21 -> 22 with fedup

Tags: fedora

The update process after booting *FedUp* silently stopped by about 80%. The system boots and even my Cinnamon starts and I can use many apps.

But there are now partially .fc21 packages installed and partially .fc22 ones.

```
# dnf list > packages.list
# grep -n Available packages.list 
6462:Available Packages
# head -6461 packages.list > packages-installed.list
#  grep .fc22 packages-installed.list | wc -l 
3101
# grep .fc21 packages-installed.list | wc -l 
3235
# dnf repolist 
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:01:15 ago on Thu May 28 16:57:26 2015.
repo id                                                repo name                                                                 status
*fedora                                                Fedora 21 - x86_64                                                        42,816
google-chrome                                          google-chrome                                                                  3
rpmfusion-free                                         RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Free                                              470
rpmfusion-free-updates                                 RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Free - Updates                                    397
rpmfusion-nonfree                                      RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Nonfree                                           178
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                              RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Nonfree - Updates                                 307
*updates                                               Fedora 21 - x86_64 - Updates                                              17,014
```

When I first called `dnf repolist` it were all Fedora 22 repos. I tried some `rpm --rebuilddb` and `dnf distro-sync` (without really knowing what I'm doing). For example:

```
# dnf list kernel
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:17:17 ago on Thu May 28 16:57:26 2015.
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                  3.19.5-200.fc21                                                  @System
kernel.x86_64                                                  3.19.7-200.fc21                                                  @System
kernel.x86_64                                                  4.0.4-301.fc22                                                   @System
# uname -r
3.19.7-200.fc21.x86_64
```

If anybody has any idea how I could maybe repair this system without completely reinstall it, I'd appreciate any hint...

---

For the case anybody wonders about the `wc -l` results -- some lines were wrapped in the `dnf list` ouput:

```
# grep -e "^    " packages-installed.list | wc -l 
102
# grep -e "^    " packages-installed.list | head -2
                                         1:0.9.10.2-5.fc21               @System
                                         1:1.0.2-1.fc22                  @System
# grep -v .fc2[21] packages-installed.list | wc -l
125
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem. We didn't do a mass rebuild for F22, so some packages which were last built in the F21 timeframe are still labeled with F21.

You're not the only one with this worry, though, so we wrote an article about it on Fedora Magazine — see [Fedora 22 will contain some fc21 packages](http://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-22-will-contain-fc21-packages/).

Comment: Thank you. I found some more problems and installed completely new today. I indeed have some fc21 packages again now.